# Is it possible to import html files throught phpmyadmin into templates table in database?

Tags: phpmyadmin, modx, modx-revolution

I have more than 300 html files which must become templates in modx. I don’t want to import them manually one by one. Is it possible to import this files through phpmyadmin into templates table in database. If it’s possible how to do it?

Comment: Did you try built-in MODX Import functionality? /manager/?a=system/import/html ?

Comment: Yes, tried, but I found it inconvenient due to the large number of steps with a large number of files. No alternatives to php my admin found yet